# MySQL выбор таблицы исходя из значения поля

Tags: mysql, sql, реляционная-модель

Даны две таблицы

```
tables
----------
ID   Tablename
1    first
2    second

items
----------
ID   tableID
1    2
2    1
```

Каким образом я могу сделать выборку всех элементов из таблицы, имея лишь айди из таблицы items, по которой можно получить название самой таблицы.
Допустим если items.ID = 1, то items.tableID = 2 => надо сделать выборку всех элементов в таблице 'second'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @tableName = (SELECT Tablename FROM `tables` WHERE ID IN (SELECT tableId FROM items WHERE ID = 1) LIMIT 0,1);
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from ', @tableName); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```